# React Hooks useCallback and useEffect causes infinite loop in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, usecallback

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
    let { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    );
    setUser(data);
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, [getUser]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

(i can remove getUser from useEffect dependency and remove useCallback as well this will work perfectly) but i wanna try putting getUser in useEffect dependency and while doing so  need to wrap getUser in useCallback. in useCallback dependency, i put setUser it work fine but incase of putting user as useCallback dependency m getting infinite loop. why is not behaving same as setUser.

Answer (score 1):

The effect will run if `getUser` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //...
}, [getUser]);
```

And `getUser` will change if `user` changes:

```
const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
  //...
}, [user]);
```

And `getUser` changes `user`:

```
setUser(data);
```

So when the component renders, the effect executes, which calls `getUser`, which updates `user`, which changes `getUser`, which triggers the effect, which calls `getUser`, etc., etc.

The `useCallback` for `getUser` has no dependency on `user`, only on `setUser`.  Change its dependency array to reflect that:

```
const getUser = useCallback(async () => {
  //...
}, [setUser]);
```

`setUser` doesn't change, so `getUser` won't change, so the effect won't be re-invoked.

Comment: Why pass `setUser` as dependency intead of `[]` ?

Comment: @NiceBooks: Because it’s a dependency in the function.  Linters/transpilers will even complain if you don’t.  Though it’s certainly possible it’s not needed, and won’t change, it’s still good practice to include relevant dependencies because if it ever *does* change then the function would otherwise be referencing a stale version.